# Need help MySQL query. Need data from two tables

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, phpmyadmin

I am a beginner in MySQL.

**Table 1: Users**

```
ID   NAME
----------
1    XYZ
2    ABC
```

**Table 2: Task**

```
ID   TASK_NAME   ASSIGNED_BY    ASSIGNED_TO
--------------------------------------------
1    task 1         1               2 
2    task 2         2               1
```

**I want this result.**

```
ID   TASK_NAME   ASSIGNED_BY    ASSIGNED_TO
--------------------------------------------
1    task 1         XYZ             ABC 
2    task 2         ABC             XYZ
```

Comment: please visit this link if you are beginner in MySQL http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-using-joins.htm it will helps you more

Comment: Then once you tried some code and you can't figure it out, come back for help and edit your question.

Comment: Looks very much like homework to me. Let us know what you have tried already and what you're stuck on.

Answer (score 1):

Its a simple `JOIN` task:

```sql
SELECT t.ID, t.TASK_NAME, 
       u1.NAME AS ASSIGNED_BY,
       u2.NAME AS ASSIGNED_TO
FROM Task AS t
JOIN Users AS u1 ON t.ASSIGNED_BY = u1.ID
JOIN Users AS u2 ON t.ASSIGNED_TO = u2.ID
```

Comment: How can I add where condition in above query?

Comment: @aasimbairagdar You can add it right at the bottom of the query.

Comment: @aasimbairagdar Glad I was able to help. Please mark this, or any other, answer as accepted if it helped you solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `JOIN` to do it. I use `INNER JOIN` please try the following query.

```
SELECT t.ID, t.TASK_NAME, 
       u1.NAME AS ASSIGNED_BY,
       u2.NAME AS ASSIGNED_TO
FROM Task AS t
INNER JOIN Users AS u1 ON t.ASSIGNED_BY = u1.ID
INNER JOIN Users AS u2 ON t.ASSIGNED_TO = u2.ID
```